# Lua: Replace characters in a string

Tags: replace, lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

I have strings like

```
abcdef
abcd|(
abcde|(foo 
abcd|)
abcde|)foo
```

which should be modified to

```
abcdef
abcd
abcde \foo 
abcd
abcde \foo
```

- if there is no `|` then do nothing
- if nothing follows the `|(` or `|)` then delete these two characters
- if something follows then replace `|(` or `|)` with `<space>\`

I am interested in short pattern expressions, if possible. I can do this by several `string.find` and `string.sub` but then I have a *lot of* `if` statements.

Comment: Do you mean the position at the end of the string with `if nothing follows`?

Comment: Yes, then `|(` or `|)` are the last characters. If there is no `|`, then `bar)` should be unchanged

Comment: Then my solution should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
function repl(v)
    res, _ = string.gsub(v:gsub('|[()]$', ''), '|[()]', ' \\')
    return res
end
```

See [Lua demo online](https://ideone.com/icfu0J)

**Details**

- `'|[()]$'` matches `|` and then either `(` or `)` at the end of the string, and `string.gsub` replaces these occurrences with an empty string
- `|[()]` then matches `|` and then either `(` or `)` *anywhere* in the string, and `string.gsub` replaces these occurrences with a space and `\`.

Comment: Ups, I just realized that I forget something. A string like `abcd|foo` is also possible and should be changed to `abcd \foo`.

Comment: @Herbert Replace `'|[()]'` with `'|[()]?'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how to replace the `[[_TOC_]]` in lua script? it has special characters.

Comment: @H_H Only `[` is special, so `%[%[_TOC_]]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I apply same rules for `[^\%[2\%]^]` string but, it doesn't work. I have tried with `%[^\%%[2\%]^]`. Am I missing something here? I am trying to replace in lua script. Thanks!

Comment: tried this as well `%[%^%[2%]%^%]`

Comment: @H_H If the string to remove is `[^\%[2\%]^]` the pattern is `%[%^\%%%[2\%%]%^]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I found correct pattern is `%[%^\\%[2\\%]%^%]`. thanks for helping!